How can I make tests completely independent of one another?
Are there any commands or settings in anchor I can use so that between each test, the state completely resets?
I am running into an issue where I initialise my program in one test, and if I try to initialise in a different testing file I get the error "Allocate: account Address already in use."
Of course this makes sense given its running on the same test validator, but is there any way to reset the validator so tests are completely independent of one another?

You'll need to use another testing tool like solana-bankrun or solana-program-test if you want your tests to run independently of each other.
